# Python : Dynamic file handlers and handling them using data structures

Tags: python, dynamic, handler, file-handling

I have a huge file of around 5-10 GBs which has syntax as shown below.

"some text" condition1

"some text" condition2

"some text" condition3

"some text" condition1

"some text" condition4

& so on

The intent is to write a fast & efficient code to create separate files to store this text info based on conditions. All lines with condition1 will go to a file named "condition1.txt".

The limitation is that we do not know the unique conditions.

How can I dynamically generate new file handlers on the fly while reading the file line by line and keep track of these handlers using condition as key and handler as the value in a python dictionary? I can use other data structures as well. Need suggestions !

Comment: what have you done so far

Comment: @Ade_1 I also have thought of the same method which Guy mentioned below in the comments. But my intent is to exercise a new method where we can handle file handling objects dynamically. I have tried looking for such a method everywhere but did not find anything. Hence, I raised this question here to get some insights from fellow programmers.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind for me would be to use the append feature on Python file handlers. You could do something like this for each line of text:

```py
def writecond(text, cond):
    fname = cond + '.txt'
    with open(fname, 'a') as file:
        file.write(text)
```

Another thing you could do is have a `dict` which maps you condition text to a list of open file handlers (although I think there might be a hard limit to the number of handlers you can have on some systems), but just be sure to close all of them before your function exits!

EDIT:

If you want the dictionary case, here's the code for that:

```py
fh_assign = {}

def writeline(text, condition):
    if condition not in fh_assign.keys():
        fh = open(f'{condition}.txt', 'w')
        fh.write(text)
        fh_assign[condition] = fh
    else:
        fh_assign[condition].write(text)
```

Once you're done with the calls to `writeline`, just iterate through the list as follows and close all the connections.

```py
for _, fh in fh_assign:
    fh.close()
```

Comment: Guy your solution looks convincing. But is there any method to prepare a list of file handling objects? Do we have any library which can generate object which can be used for file handling as well can be stored in list/dict ?

Comment: If you wanted to prepare a list of file handlers beforehand you would need to pre-parse the file, although given the large size this might take a while. Using a dict allows you to add items on the fly and has faster lookup times, so I'm not sure why you would pre-make a list. Also, this method will give some results even if the program exits while parsing.

Comment: I agree with your point. Just out of box (for other scenarios),  even if I make a handler dynamically that will be of string type . Can you show me how you are thinking of making an object and adding it to list and then use it back?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking me how to make a file handler? In that case you'd use `fh = open('fname', 'a')` and then just add them to the list/dict like any other object. If you don't want to have multiple handles open, you can just use the solution above for each line and it'll work the same. If you wanted to store the information in separate lists without writing, then that's a different question altogether.

Comment: The above solution will open the file in append mode for every line. It will increase the IO instructions. I found a way and adding it below. Please check and share your comment on it.

Comment: Oh I understand, I'll post alternate code for the dictionary case above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233022/discussion-between-johnny-and-guy-marino).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one option of handling objects dynamically and keeping track of it.

```
file_handler = {}

with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.split()[1] not in file_handler.keys():
            file_handler[line.split()[1]] = open(line.split()[1],"w")
            file_handler[line.split()[1]].write(line.split()[0])
        else:
            file_handler[line.split()[1]].write(line.split()[0])
f.close()

for key in file_handler.keys():
    file_handler[key].close()
```